Error parsing config from lua tables in boost unit test
Config file are read from my project directory, each of them run normally when I execute the main project target. I have an issue running a test case. I'm using sol2 from here as the lua-managing library.
stack trace of error

The code I'm running is pretty simple:
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SCENARIO_LOGIN_TEST)
{
    sZone->general_conf().set_test_run();

    sZone->general_conf().set_config_file_path("../../../../../config/zone-server.lua.dist");
    sZone->read_config();
    
    sZone->config().set_static_db_path(std::string("../../../../../db/"));
    HLog(info) << "Static database path set to " << sZone->config().get_static_db_path() << "";

    sZone->config().set_mapcache_path(std::string("../../../../../db/maps.dat"));
    HLog(info) << "Mapcache file name is set to " << sZone->config().get_mapcache_path() << ", it will be read while initializing maps.";

    sZone->config().set_script_root_path(std::string("../../../../../scripts/"));

    sZone->initialize();
    sZone->finalize();
}

Any more project related code can be found here
